# How to subscribe to a pocketbase collection with sveltekit?

Tags: typescript, database, real-time, sveltekit, pocketbase

I'm trying to make my sveltekit project realtime. My problem is that I have to reload the page if I want to see changes in another instance.

I tried to subscribe to the collection with onMount() from +page.svelte (like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUYBFDPZ5qk&t=657s)
but when I ran it it said:  *can't import $env static private into client side code* so I kept the part of the code that worked.

Is there a way to listen to changes from the +page.server.ts and update the UI accordingly?
I struggle to find the right place for this code: https://pocketbase.io/docs/api-realtime/

+page.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
    export let data 
    $: products  = data.products

</script>

<div class="app">

    <div class="list ">
        <h2>Products:</h2>
        {#each products as product}
        <!-- content here -->
        <ul>
            <li>{product.name}:<br>{product.price}$ 
                <form method="POST" action="?/buy_product">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value={product.id}>
                    <button type="submit">Buy</button>
                </form></li>
        </ul>
        {/each}
    </div>
    <div class=" add-product">
        <form method="POST" action="?/add_product" use:enhance
        class="add-form">
            <h2>Add</h2>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="add-input">
            <input type="number" name="price" class="add-input">
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
...
</style>
```

+page.server.ts:

```js
import { pb } from '$lib/server/pocketbase';


export async function load() {
    const records =  await pb.collection('products').getList(1, 50, {})
    const productData = records.items   
    return {
        products: productData
    };

}
/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions = {
    add_product: async ({request}) => {
        const form = await request.formData()
        const product = {
            "name": form.get('name'),
            "price": form.get('price')
        };
        const record = await pb.collection('products').create(product);
    },
    buy_product: async ({request}) => {
        const form = await request.formData()
        let id = form.get('id') as string
        
        await pb.collection('products').delete(id);
    },
};
```